# Highmaps - Printing resizes the map on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, highcharts, highmaps

On Google Chrome, printing a Highmap makes it resize and stick to the left. But the map won't take its initial shape after printing. See this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5u6z7csf/1/

The code is very basic :

> $(function () {
>       $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=germany.geo.json&callback=?',
>   function (geojson) {
>
> ```
>     var data = Highcharts.geojson(geojson, 'map');
>     $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
>         series: [{
>             data: data
>         }]
>     });
> });
> ```

I tested it on IE and Firefox and it works fine using them.

Is there a way to walk around this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the reporting, it is requested [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2088)